# Initial delay for ZIO ZSchedule

Tags: scala, schedule, zio

The schedule I'm trying to make would have to:

1. Start after a specified delay
2. Repeat at a fixed rate
3. Terminate if it reaches given time limit or encounters terminating state

So what I have is (2.) and (3.):

```scala
val repeatUntilTimeLimitReached =
  ZSchedule
    .fixed(config.pollingConfig.pollInterval)
    .untilOutput(pollingTimeLimitReached)

val untilTermination = Schedule.doUntil[RebootState](_.terminatesPolling)

val schedule = repeatUntilTimeLimitReached *> untilTermination
```

I tried `ZSchedule.delayed()`, but it seems to add delay to subsequent schedules too.

So is there any way to add intial delay to `ZSchedule` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a small discussion with community it seems that expected behaviour is not achievable with `Schedule` (ZIO version: 1.0.0-RC15), since it is used to repeat after the first execution.

I've ended up using `ZIO.sleep()` and `schedule` I made in the original post:

```scala
val schedule = repeatUntilTimeLimitReached *> untilTermination       

for {
  _     <- ZIO.sleep(initialDelay)
  state <- doStuff().repeat(schedule)
} yield state
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add another *Schedule* and compose them:

```
val delayedSchedule = Schedule.once.delayed(_ + 12.seconds)

val schedule = delayedSchedule *> repeatUntilTimeLimitReached *> untilTermination
```

I played a bit with this and you need to `flatMap` the *Schedules*.

Here I use an example that uses `zio.console`:

```
import zio.console._
import zio.duration._
import zio.{App, Schedule, ZIO}

  val s = Schedule.spaced(1.second)
  for {
    _ <- putStrLn("Start")
    _ <- putStrLn("Initial Delay").delay(5.seconds)
    _ <- putStrLn("Repeated Delay").repeat(s)
  } yield ()
```

Comment: This way it: 
`runs once > waits 12 seconds > runs once > exits`

I would like it not running at all at first.

Comment: @EnergyCreator you are right - I added an update to my question

Comment: The updated version of your answer works, but the original question was if it is possible to create a `ZSchedule` with an initial delay. Either way `ZIO.sleep()` looks cleaner than delaying some random effect.